# Perl HTTP::Request - best way to parse the query-paramters

Tags: perl, http

I get an object HTTP::Request out of a webserver if a request occurs. I only see GET-query-parameters in the URL or if it is from a POST in the header.

Is there a way HTTP::Request or any other package gives me these parameters in a nice way (e.g. a hash) and I do not need to parse it my myself?

e.g. GET
http://example.net?a=3&b=jack

I'd like to access the value of a (= 3) and b (= jack) without parse it manually from the URL or the HTTP-Header (if POST).

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks for the good advice about the package URI. It works perfectly for parameters in the URL.

But not for POST where the parameters are in the body. I adapted it for that.

```
if ($req->method eq "POST")      # $req is HTTP::Request
{           {
  my $uri = URI->new ("/whatever?" . $req->content);  # not very pretty
  %params = $uri->query_form ();
  ...
```

to get the same results. Do you think thats a good idea or is there a better  - more straighter way??

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::QueryParam, https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use List::Util qw( pairs );   # Version 1.29+
use URI        qw( );

my $uri = URI->new( $request->uri );

# If none of the parameters can have multiple values.
# Usage: my $value = $params{$key};
my %params = $uri->query_form();

# If some of the parameters can have multiple values.
# Usage: my $value  = $params{$key}[0];
# Usage: my @values = @{ $params{$key} };
my %params;
for my $pair ( pairs $uri->query_form() ) {
   my ( $key, $value ) = @$pair;
   push @{ $params{$key} }, $value;
}
```

[URI::QueryParam](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI::QueryParam) adds methods to `$uri` that appear to be convenient in this situation (`query_param` and `query_form_hash`), but are far too error-prone to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use `URI::QueryString::query_form_hash` like this (Perl debugger session):

```perl
  DB<2> use URI::QueryParam
  DB<4> use URI
  DB<5> $u = URI->new('http://server:52907/wsapi/decrypt/?otp=foobar')
  DB<6> x $u->query_param
0  'otp'
  DB<7> x $u->query_form_hash
0  HASH(0x27c75a8)
   'otp' => 'foobar'
  DB<9> x $u->path
0  '/wsapi/decrypt/'
```